# Suppose a graph $G$ is connected with $n$ vertices and $e$ edges. If $n \geq 3$ and $G$ has exactly one cycle, prove that $e=n$.

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose a graph $G$ is connected with $n$ vertices and $e$ edges. If $n \ge 3$ and $G$ has exactly one cycle, prove that $e = n$.

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Let $C$ be the only cycle in $G$. Consider any two adjacent vertices $u$ & $v$ that belong to $C$. Even if I remove the edge between $u$ & $v$, $G$ will remain connected. Let $G'$ be the new graph after removing the edge $uv$. $G'$ is connected, and has no cycle (bcoz we removed the $uv$ edge), hence $G'$ is a tree. $G'$ has $n-1$ edges $\implies$ $G$ has $n$ edges.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the spanning tree of the graph $G$, The number of edges in the spanning tree is $n-1$. As $G$ has only one cycle, we can add only one more edge to the spanning tree to get the cycle(as any edges added to the spanning tree create a cycle), so $G$ has $n$ edges.